# Typescript ts-check javascript generics

Tags: javascript, typescript, definitelytyped

Using TypeScript's new ts-check, I can't figure out how to handle working with a generic function.

```
/**
 * @type {Reducer<IPoiState, any>}
 */
const poi = handleActions({
  [ADD_BOOKMARK_START]: (state) => {
    return { ...state };
  },
}, {});
```

The handleActions type comes from Definitey Typed and looks like...

```
export function handleActions<State>(
    reducerMap: ReducerMap<State>,
    initialState: State
): Reducer<State, any>;
```

So, I'm getting an error saying that...

```
Type 'Reducer<{}, any>' is not assignable to type 'Reducer<IPoiState, any>'.
  Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'IPoiState'.
```

Is there anyway to force the generic through?

Comment: What does `IPoiState` look like?

Comment: I can only guess but I would think that the type that is coming out of your `handleActions` declaration is wrong. Are `State` and `IPoiState` also somewhere in the type system? The type system is incorrectly determining that `handleActions` returns `Reducer<{}, any>`, so you need to get it to actually be of type `Reducer<State, any>`, (and I assume also to get it to recognize that `State` is a `IPoiState`).

Answer (score 1):

You can cast or type assert the object by adding the Type you want it to be in front with angle braces like this `<IPoiState>{}`.

[Type Assertion](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/types/type-assertion.html)

Comment: should not be necessary since TypeScript has 'duck typing'.

Comment: @Sahuagin Ineresting, in this case we would need to see what IPoistate looks like to know if the methods are supported.

Comment: Well, now that I think of it, since he's using a variable `ADD_BOOKMARK_START` as the member name, then maybe you are right, and a cast is needed. If I set up a similar example, it won't work unless I use one.

Comment: Keep in mind, the code above is JavaScript, not TypeScript.

Comment: @jcreamer898 Why is the transpiler being run against it if its not TypeScript? Or do you mean your function is meant to be pure JS?

Comment: There is a new feature of typescript called `ts-check` that will type check JavaScript files. :)